# Reverse String by character class within a string in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, string

I need to turn this `["abc123!@#\n314159","987bbc\n#$%\nxyz886"]`

Into this `["zyx688\n%$#\n789cbb","951413\ncba321#@!"]`

My current code:

```
function reverseAll(arr){
  //coding here...
  var reversedArr = [];
  (function(){
    arr.reverse()
  })();
  (function(){
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        reversedArr.push(arr[i].split('\n').reverse())       
      }
  })();
  console.log (reversedArr)
}
```

logs `[ [ 'xyz886', '#$%', '987bbc' ], [ '314159', 'abc123!@#' ] ]`

Im having trouble with reversing the individual strings by the character class, I think I might be able to use regex but not sure what to do.

Comment: Joining back to a single string is not an issue.

Comment: The logic of expected output is not clear to me

Comment: A link to the codewars kata with instructions https://www.codewars.com/kata/ttt-number-8-reverse-all/train/javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the following method to get the expected reversing:

```js
function reverseAll(data)
{
 var output=[];
  for(var j=data.length-1;j>=0;j--){
  var rev = "";
  var arr=data[j].split("\n");
  const regex = /\d+|[a-zA-Z]+|[^\da-zA-Z]+/g;
  let m;

    for(var i=arr.length-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
      while ((m = regex.exec(arr[i])) !== null) 
           rev+=m[0].split("").reverse().join("");
       if(i>0)
         rev+='\n';
    }
  output.push(rev);
  }
 return output;
}

console.log(reverseAll(["abc123!@#\n314159","987bbc\n#$%\nxyz886"]));
```

Comment: I haven’t had a chance to test this, but does it differentiate between numbers and symbols as well? If so, where? To me it looks like it differentiates between letters and everything else.

Comment: there are three differentiations ... numbers,  alphabets and anything else ... and it is differentiated by this regex: `/\d+|[a-zA-Z]+|[^\da-zA-Z]+/g`

Comment: Ah d+ is digits. Thank you